# Trying to use a numeric operator from a list

Tags: python, operators, numeric

Is there any way to use a numeric operator from a list in a sum. For example, if I had a list called `BASICOPS`, which consisted of `['+']`, could I then use it in a sum, which is for example:

```
(1,(BASICOPS),2)
```

to make the sum `1+2`?
I am trying to do this to make a game where the operator for a question is random. So in the game the list would have mulitple operators, and these would be selected randomly using their index, which would be randomly selected.

Comment: `eval(''.join(['1', '+', '2']))` returns 3, but I think you'll need to make some modifications for what you want.

Comment: i'm shooting around in the dark, i'm new to python. so far i attempted to name the variable + 'ADD', with there being apostrophes around the +.